# DataTables unable to display the field of related object in LWC

Tags: javascript, datatable, apex, lwc

I have a data table which displays 'Name' field and 'Address' field (Address related to another object). The 'Name' field is displayed properly but if I iterate over the list in html for `pcon.Address__r.Name` it gives error. If only `pcon.Address__r` is given , it shows `[object object]` in table. Can anybody resolve this issue?

HTML:

```html
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #151963;color: white;">Name</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #151963;color: white;">Address</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <template for:each={pconfig} for:item="pcon" for:index="i">
             <tr class={pcon.row} data-id={pcon.Id} data-index={i} key={pcon.Id} onclick{getquotes} >
                    <td>{pcon.Name}</td>
                    <td>{pcon.Address__r.Name}</td>
                  </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
             </table>
        </lightning-layout-item>
```

JS:

```js
 @wire(Vendor_getProduct,{ basketId: 'fef0E0000dwedjh' })
    getProducts({error,data})
    {
         if(data)
         {
            //console.log( 'Fetched Data ' + JSON.stringify( data ) );
            this.pconfig =  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( data) );
            console.log('products are:',data);
         }
         else if(error){
            
            this.error=data;
            console.log('error is undefined');
         } 
    }
```

class:

```
public class c {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Product_Configuration__c> getProduct (Id basketId) {
       
        return [select  id, 
                        name, 
                        Address__r.name, 
                       from  Product_Configuration__c
 where  Product_Basket__c =:basketId];
    }
```

Comment: Your class returns `Address__r.name` but your table uses `<td>{pcon.Address__r.Name}</td>`. Change `Name` to `name` in your table definition.

Comment: @andrewJames even that way it is not working .

Comment: I get the error as  [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')] I get the error as